# Deserialize XML InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to deserialize xml file by this guide: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/487571/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part-2

But when I run app, I am getting the following exception: InvalidOperationException - error in XML document (2,2)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Address));
   TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\data.xml");
   object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
   Address XmlData = (Address)obj;
   reader.Close();
}
public class Address
{
   public int HouseNo { get; set; }
   public string StreetName { get; set; }
   public string City { get; set; }
}
```

here is my XML:

```
<Address>
    <HouseNo>4</HouseNo>
    <StreetName>Rohini</StreetName>
    <City>Delhi</City>
</Address>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce - see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q11HKK).  Are you certain that's exactly your XML?  The error implies there is something wrong with the syntax of your XML on line 2... and there's nothing wrong wth the XML you've included.

Comment: Encoding problem I feel.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its because you have put your "Address" class inside "Program" class like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args){...}
    class Address{...}
}
```

to fix this just move your "Address" out of "Program" like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args){...}
}
class Address{...}
```

Comment: That won't make any difference, it would work fine either way (see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q11HKK)).